# Vue Property XXX was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-props

Could someone please advise why I am getting the error message: Property XXX was accessed during render but is not defined on instance?

Context:
I have created a "project" component and I am displaying 3 of these child components inside of a "projectgrid" parent component. Each project has an object defined in the "projectgrid" data function. I want to iterate over these project data objects to render all of the child elements. The base configuration is appearing but none of the props I am passing from the data objects (from parent to child) are appearing and I am getting the above error.

projectgrid parent component:

```
    <template>
      <div class="project-container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col" v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index">
              <Project />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import Project from "@/components/Project.vue";
    export default {
      name: "Projectgrid",
      components: {
        Project,
      },
      data() {
        return {
          projects: [
            {
              title: "Project 1",
              image: "",
              langInfo: "loremipsum",
              description: "loremipsum",
              codeLink: "loremipsum",
              siteLink: "loremipsum",
            },
            {
              title: "Project 2",
              image: "",
              langInfo: "loremipsum.",
              description: "loremipsum",
              codeLink: "loremipsum",
              siteLink: "loremipsum",
            },
            {
          title: "Project 3",
          image: "",
          langInfo: "loremipsum.",
          description: "loremipsum",
          codeLink: "loremipsum",
          siteLink: "loremipsum",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

project child component:

```
<template>
  <div class="project">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem">
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1597838816882-4435b1977fbe?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2049&q=80"
        class="card-img-top"
        alt="..."
      />
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{ title }}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-lang-info">Written with {{ langInfo }}</h6>
        <p class="card-text">
          {{ description }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <a :href="codeLink" class="card-link"><i class="bi bi-github"></i></a>
        <a v-if="(title = Portfolio)" class="card-link project-link"
          ><i class="bi bi-link-45deg"></i
        ></a>
        <a v-else :href="siteLink" class="card-link project-link"
          ><i class="bi bi-link-45deg"></i
        ></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Project",
  props: {
    portfolio: {
      title: String,
      image: Image,
      langInfo: String,
      description: String,
      codeLink: String,
      siteLink: String,
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The projects are successfully iterated over and they are displaying with the hard coded data, but none of the props are displaying. Someone please assist? Thanks

Comment: You’re not passing any props to the `Project` component. Moreover in the `Project` component you are not accessing the nested properties in the portfolio prop correctly. For example, `description` should be `portfolio.description`

Comment: In addition to the problems @Terry mentioned, your `props` definition in the `Project` component is incorrect too. It should be defined like this: `props: { portfolio: { type: Object, required: true } }`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback - would that be done by binding the Project component in the projectgrid code? Also, is what I am trying to achieve possible so that the Project component is just the template? Would this also be done by binding each iteration to one of the projects in the data function?